# How can we verify BGLS aggregate signatures in Solidity?

Tags: signature, cryptography, byzantium, pairings

BGLS [1] is an aggregate signature scheme by Boneh et al., that allows aggregation of signatures on n different messages from n different signers. What I want to achieve is to verify such signatures in a smart contract.

Verification of a single signature (a BLS signature) is done through checking equality `e(g1, σ) == e(v, h)`, where:

- e : G1 x G2 -> GT is a bilinear pairing/mapping
- g1 is a generator of G1
- σ is the signature
- v is the public key of the signer
- h is the hash of the signed message

Using the new precompiled contract `bn256Pairing` introduced in Byzantium (and also `bn256Add` and `bn256ScalarMul`), we can check the equality and verify the signature.

**Problem:**
Now, to verify an aggregate signature, we need to compute: 
`e(g1, σ) == product of e(vi, hi) for all signers i`
where vi and hi are the public key and hashed message of signer i.

This seems to be more difficult as we must actually calculate the pairings en multiply them before checking the equality. However, the precompiled contract only allows for checking equality. Also, I found an implementation on GitHub (Project-Arda/bgls-on-evm [2]), but it only seems capable of verifying single signatures.

**Question:** 
Does anyone have a suggestion on how to verify this aggregate signature in Solidity?

Note: BGLS is originally not compatible with the type 3 pairings that are supported by Ethereum, but the scheme can be modified as suggested by Chatterjee et al. [3].

**References:**

- [1]: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-39200-9_26
- [2]: https://github.com/Project-Arda/bgls-on-evm
- [3]: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10623-009-9334-7

**Update (8 July 2018):**

An example of how I verify BLS and BGLS signatures in Solidity is found at https://gist.github.com/BjornvdLaan/ca6dd4e3993e1ef392f363ec27fe74c4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is actually just a notational issue. In the original paper the groups are written multiplicatively, while the groups in the Ethereum docs are written additively.

In particular,

```
e(g1, σ) = e(g1, x1*h1+x2*h2+...) = x1*e(g1,h1) + x2*e(g1,h2)+...+xn*e(g1,hn)
```

Then you can do the check simply by using the n-ary pairing check

```
e(-g1, σ, v1, h1, v2, h2, ..., vn, hn)
```

Comment: Hi Tjaden, thanks for your answer! I will try this in the coming days and either accept your answer or come back with comments.

Comment: I tested your solution for 2 and 3 signers, and it is working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Saffie, Do you know how to verify the BLS in etherum if the pairing is based on discrete logarithmic  as described in the original paper of BLS as follows `Let PG be a pairing group generator that on input $1^k$ outputs descriptions of multiplicative groups $G_1$ and $G_T$ of prime order $p$ where $|p| =k$. Let     and let $g \in G_1^{*}$ and $G_{1}^{*}=G_{1} \backslash\{1\}$
.The generated groups are such that there exists an admissible bilinear map $e : G_1 × G_1 → G_T$, meaning that (1) for all $a, b ∈ Z_p$  it holds that  $e(g^a,g^b )=e(g,g)^{ab}$ (2) $e(g,g)≠1$`

Comment: The original paper gives a construction that works in any gap-DH group with a pairing function. Ethereum only supports the bn256 groups so you don't worry about the pairing group generator, there's only one pairing group you can use

Comment: Exactly what @TjadenHess comments. I specifically used an edited version of the BLS scheme that supports the pairing that is supported by Ethereum. You can also review my comments and findings in my paper: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/330521303_MUSCLE_Authenticated_External_Data_Retrieval_from_Multiple_Sources_for_Smart_Contracts

Comment: @TjadenHess Could you please suggest an  answer to this question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/71750/how-the-following-pairing-equality-be-verified-in-etherum-smart-contracts