# How to compute pairing in a smart contract

Tags: solidity, cryptography, zksnark, zero-knowledge, pairings

I am working on the elliptic curve and pairing stuff in Ethereum smart contract. How can I compute pairing such e(p1,p2)?

I know that we have a pre-compile pairing check in Ethereum client which is live at 0x08, and performs the pairing check.

> From the documentation:

```
success := call(sub(gas, 2000), 8, 0, add(input, 0x20), mul(inputSize, 0x20), out, 0x20)
```

This means we can just check equality of two pairings in a smart contract. However, I require the computation of exactly one pairing such as e(p1,p2)=? in Solidity.

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/71750/how-the-following-pairing-equality-be-verified-in-etherum-smart-contracts

Comment: @eth no. I want to compute exactly of pairing not just equality check.

Comment: The prior comment was just a way to force a link to your(?) other question.  Because no one has been able to answer these yet, I would suggest trying to look at Ethereum projects working on privacy and ask them these questions, and you can self-answer here what you learn.